# Application of he Harnack's inequality tto prove a $max $ $min$ inequality

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Let u be a harmonic non negative function in $\Omega=B(0,1)\setminus\{0\} \in\mathbb R^n$. 
I would like to show that there exists a constant c, depending just on $n$ such that 
$$
\max_{\partial B(0,r)} u \leq c \min_{\partial B(0,r)} u
$$
for every $0<r\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

My attempt is to use the Harnack's inequality which implies that for all the balls $B(x_0,r) $ s.t. $B(x_0,4r)\subset \Omega$, $x_0 \in \Omega$, then 
$$
\max_{ \overline{B(x_0,r)}} u \leq 3^n \min_{\overline{ B(0,r)}} u
$$
Then I would use the maximum principle to conclude.

The problem is that for every $r$ the ball $B(0,1)$ does not belong to $\Omega$, hence I am not able to apply the Harnack's inequality. 
How could I avoid this problem?